# gulp-neuter just compiles first and last

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to neuter all my app JS files. But `gulp-neuter` fails.

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task(
    'app:neuter',
    function()
    {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var util = require('gulp-util');

        return gulp.src([
            dirs.app + 'app.js',
            dirs.app + 'router.js',
            dirs.app + 'services/**/*.js',
            dirs.app + 'directives/**/*.js',
            dirs.app + 'routes/**/*.js'
        ])
            .pipe(plugins.neuter('app.js', 'app.map.js', {
                template: '{%= src %}',
                filepathTransform : function (file)
                {
                    if (file.substr(-3) !== '.js')
                    {
                        file += '.js';
                    }
                    if (file.indexOf('*') === -1)
                    {
                        fs.access(file, fs.R_OK, function(err){
                            if (err) util.warn('File not found: ' + file);
                        });
                    }
                    return file;
                }
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.temp))
            .pipe(gulp.src(dirs.temp + 'app.js').pipe(gulp.dest(dirs.dest)));
    }
);
```

My files got the following structure:

**app/app.js**:

```
//app code
```

**app/router.js**:

```
require('app/app.js');
//router code
```

**app/services/my-service.js**:

```
require('app/app.js');
//service code
```

As you can see, I have several folders and files to access for, but output file just contains first and last one.